# JUnitTest failing when creating subclass object

Tags: java, junit, abstract-class

I got this superclass where I have some methods, one method is:

```
abstract public void setHP(int health);
```

In my subclass I have this method

```
public void setHP(int health){ super.health = health }
```

I then wrote a JUnitTest:

```
    @Test
    public void testEliteHetestUalth()
    {
        Subclass unit = new Subclass();
        ...
    }
```

And here it just fails, it's like I cant create an object of the subclass. Is there anything special about creating objects for subclasses? I hope I gave enough information.

Comment: Fails how? Any exception?

Comment: No, it's in JUnit. It doesn't give any exception... just highlights the line where I try to create the object

Comment: We'll need more information than that; creating an instance is creating an instance.

Comment: So, it doesn't even compile? Do you have a no-arg constructor in `Subclass`?

Comment: Please post your code as an [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: did you implement the `setHP()` method in your subclass? `setHealth(int)` is not the same as `setHP()`.

Comment: Sorry, fixed parameter and method name. There's no arg constructor.

Comment: If not clear enough, I have an attribute named health in superclass

Comment: This is far from [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, everything works fine:

I have superclass:

```
package tests;

public class Superclass {

    int health;

}
```

subclass:

```
package tests;

public class Subclass extends Superclass {

    public void setHP(int health){ 
        super.health = health; 
    }
}
```

and test:

```
package tests;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MyJUnit {

    @Test
    public void testEliteHetestUalth() {
        Subclass unit = new Subclass();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry for posting bad information.. will do better next time. I can now see that I did something in my superclass constructor that for some reason failed in junit. Thanks